# NLog WebServiceTarget

Tags: nlog

I'm trying to use the webservicetarget to send an email, but can't figure out how to pass an authorization header with it.  Is there any way to add a custom header (like x-api-key) to the NLog web service target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GitHub PR that adds support for HTTP-headers (with PreAuthenticate):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/1912

Comment: Gotcha, looks like it might be rolled up into v5.0 whenever that comes out, thanks!